# Multiple ViewController - Best Approach

Tags: iphone, ipad, view, uisplitviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have a very large form to build in my ipad application and I'm note sure which approach( between create multiple views in or multiple viewcontrollers ) to follow. Well, I have decided to split may form in logical sections, so I want use a splitviewcontroller with a root( a tableviewcontroller with the sections) and multipleviecontrollers for each sections. When the user select a row in tableview I will show the correspondent viewcontroller. I'm saving a reference for each viewcontroller in my app_delegate and the app_delegate also is the responsible for change the viewcontrollers. Is this the best approach? There is other approach to follow? About the multiple view I was thinking to put multiple view in the same xib file and then choose based in tag as the use tap the row in rootviewcontroller's tableview.

Thanks in advance. And sorry for my bad english.. Learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will say this on the subject: currently, having multiple view controllers on the screen at the same time can be problematic if you're not using one of Apple's existing classes, such as a `UISplitViewController`.

The main issue is that important events your view controllers will want to respond to (rotation events, etc) won't be passed down to them. It's not a *huge* pain, it's just something to need to take into account - you'd typically create your own parent view controller that could pass these events down to its children.

Now, you are using a split view controller, so alls well on that front. There is no provided way for detail and master controllers in a split view controller to communicate with each other, but Apple recommend you employ a standard delegation pattern. If your application is fairly simple this could certainly happen in your app delegate as you do now.

If you're targeting iOS 5 only there are some changes that are relevant regarding multiple controllers on the screen at the same time, but I can't discuss them on here because of the NDA. You should go to Apple's developer forums (devforums.apple.com) to learnmore.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the way I am doing now I have to change the detail view controller to other view controller as the user tap a specific row in master view controller, to do that I put a navigation controller as my detail view controller and I have to change its view controllers array to bring up the correct view controller, it sounds a bad approach for me, but as I said in my question, is it? There is an property that allow us to change smoothly the detail view controller whiteout change the viewcontrollers property? Create or change the array just to achieve that sounds bad.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like I'm trying to do the same thing as you (large insurance forms here, how about your project?)  Unfortunately I can't help out as you're a bit ahead of me.  I've been able to flip back and forth between 8 detail views by tapping on the 8 rows in my UITableViewController, without keeping a reference to either the current or previous one anywhere.  The data I enter into various TextFields stays where it should.

I currently have a xxxViewController.h/.m and corresponding .xib file for each detail view.  That's an awful lot of code, but I couldn't see any other way to do it.  Now I'm having a problem getting my button pressed handlers to fire.  Also I've still got to put a database behind these screens.

Were you able to overcome your issue?

Thanks,

Jeff in Alabama

Comment: Well almost! I still using this approach and at this moment it is working fine.. Every detailView with its controller in separated files. I also didn't found any other way to do it.